# Store already stored var in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I can store the URL using

storeLocation | url

But I want to use stored Var at the storeLocation name

I want something like:

store | 1 | x

storeLocation | url_${x}

I can use  -  open | ${url_1}

But, I need to use something like:

open | ${url_${x}}  -  it does`t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masochistic way without array (That's what you want):

```
storeEval     | "url"                                | base
storeEval     | "1"                                  | lol
storeEval     | storedVars['base']+storedVars['lol'] | name
storeLocation | location
getEval       | {storedVars['${name}']=storedVars['location']}
echo          | ${url1}
```

The better way with arrays:

```
storeEval     | new Array();                         | url
storeLocation | location
getEval       | storedVars['url'].push(storedVars['location'])
echo          | javascript{storedVars['url'][0]}
```

The second variant is better because there is no need to create special variable all the time. You are doing much more readable push to the array. Also it is much easier to get access to them - you can just loop the array.

P.S. to open the page just use open instead of echo